# How to combine two queries where one of them results in an array and the second is the element place in the array?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have the following two queries:

Query #1

```
(SELECT ARRAY (SELECT (journeys.id) 
               FROM JOURNEYS 
               JOIN RESPONSES ON scenarios[1] = responses.id) AS arry);
```

This one returns an array.

Query #2:

```
SELECT (journeys_index.j_index) 
FROM journeys_index
WHERE environment = 'env1' 
  AND for_channel = 'ch1' 
  AND first_name = 'name1';
```

This second query returns the element index in the former array.

How do I combine the two to get only the element value?

Comment: Unrelated, but: the parentheses around the column names are completely useless.

Comment: Thanks. Will correct. I see also parentheses around the first query which is not needed and was left from my attempts to combine them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated a simpler example with a table containing an array column (the result of your first query)

```
create table my_array_test (id int, tst_array varchar[]);
insert into my_array_test values (1,'{cat, mouse, frog}');
insert into my_array_test values (2,'{horse, crocodile, rabbit}');
```

And another table containing the element position for each row I want to extract.

```
create table my_array_pos_test (id int, pos int);
insert into my_array_pos_test values (1,1);
insert into my_array_pos_test values (2,3);
```

e.g. from the row in `my_array_test` with `id=1` I want to extract the `1st` item (`pos=1`) and from the row in `my_array_test` with `id=2` I want to extract the `3rd` item (`pos=3`)

```
defaultdb=> select * from my_array_pos_test;
 id | pos
----+-----
  1 |   1
  2 |   3
(2 rows)
```

Now the resulting statement is

```
select *, 
tst_array[my_array_pos_test.pos] 
from
my_array_test join
my_array_pos_test on my_array_test.id = my_array_pos_test.id
```

with the expected result

```
 id |        tst_array         | id | pos | tst_array
----+--------------------------+----+-----+-----------
  1 | {cat,mouse,frog}         |  1 |   1 | cat
  2 | {horse,crocodile,rabbit} |  2 |   3 | rabbit
(2 rows)
```

Now, in your case I would probably do something similar to the below, assuming your 1st select statement returns one row only.

```
with array_sel as 
(SELECT ARRAY (SELECT (journeys.id) 
               FROM JOURNEYS 
               JOIN RESPONSES ON scenarios[1] = responses.id) AS arry)
SELECT arry[journeys_index.j_index]
FROM journeys_index cross join array_sel
WHERE environment = 'env1' 
  AND for_channel = 'ch1' 
  AND first_name = 'name1';
```

I can't validate fully the above sql statement since we can't replicate your tables, but should give you a hint on where to start from

Comment: Amazing Ftisiot. Thank you so much